# Finding the square root of a polynomial with radical

Tags: elementary-number-theory, radicals, square-numbers, diophantine-approximation

I have two positive integers, $a$ and $b$, such that
$$a^2=28b\sqrt{8b^2+1}+80b^2+5, \tag{$\star$}$$
and I’d like to find $a$ in terms of $b$ (including $\sqrt{8b^2+1}$, if necessary/appropriate), with a range like $$6b + \sqrt{8b^2+1} ≤ a ≤ 2b^2+ 3\sqrt{8b^2+1}$$ being an acceptable compromise.

I recently learned how to use Laurent series, evaluated at infinity, to approximate the square root of a polynomial, but can't figure out exactly how to apply that technique here (Wolfram gives somewhat unhelpful results) — or even figure out if it’s applicable [because of the radical].

Obviously, $b^2$ is a square triangular number (because $8b^2+1$ is a square), but I haven’t figured out how to use that detail to help me.

What’s the best approximation to the square root of ($\star$)?

Comment: @zkutch $b\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Did you try first to find the $b$'s such that $\sqrt{8b^2+1}$ is an integer ?

Comment: What's wrong with just
$$a=\pm\sqrt{28b\sqrt{8b^2+1}+80b^2+5}.$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Yes, that’s what I meant by “Obviously, $b^2$ is a square triangular number…”  =)

Comment: @Servaes: I want to find a representation without nested radicals.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are integers such that
$$a^2=28b\sqrt{8b^2+1}+80b^2+5.$$
Then in particular $\sqrt{8b^2+1}$ is an integer, and so $8b^2+1=c^2$ for some integer $c$. Then
$$a^2=28bc+10c^2-5,$$
and a bit of rearranging shows that
$$(10c^2-(a^2+5))^2=(28bc)^2=28^2b^2c^2=98(8b^2)c^2=98(c^2-1)c^2.$$
Expanding the left hand side and rearranging, we see that $c^2$ is a root of the quadratic
$$2X^2-(20a^2+2)X+(a^2+5)^2=0.$$
As $c^2$ is an integer the discriminant $\Delta$ of this quadratic is a perfect square, where
$$\Delta=(20a^2+2)^2-4\cdot2\cdot(a^2+5)^2=14^2(2a^4-1).$$
It follows that also $2a^4-1$ is a perfect square, say $d^2$, and so
$$d^2-2a^4=-1.$$
This shows that $(X,Y)=(d,a^2)$ is a solution to the Pell equation $X^2-2Y^2=-1$, and hence that $a^2$ is a [Pell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_number) that is a perfect square. That $a=13$ is the only such number is shown in [this article](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272482/1-s2.0-S0022314X05X80209/1-s2.0-S0022314X05800290/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEGEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQCZs%2Bw92oIWQCzv%2BeAXKkPMnb4nUwTAw6Np4mPFRhR2MQIgcTdalI0294eRlFOlCOPxzld%2Fpf0faVYf4iTBAOpFwxgqgwQIqv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAEGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDDl%2FI3gJZvasIc5u8SrXA3%2Blev3sKfZY65gZwAqGM%2Bmk7oraIGyMReWb3kPJZe4Z3Oq%2Fu1XQml5v%2FvbsYfeJ36MVIpS%2B4QP5R6weEFux2uJtjgOQIiSlQishB488d2al%2BmhCwdYHxiOV4DJ6A1GMB%2BULrvAVLUpQZ4Rz52Kk9HgxAdKoZnlrhKEwVjsHJRuDatDcO6wwFjebsvwYujb5i0f1%2BwdU4oNCXh%2BV5oDQhTGo2R%2FGu72WtSseLgV%2BaPyVO5oCH7X22Qx%2BujzdPHlO%2BciVq7FqGzLXfYouhz8oe4WbePMBk3y0AzDsQicTqbmsMdToDSvTuCbEfyOG0VxYZ3024tV32MZ0YrZNxh1vdkmtU%2Fc4WsQMk%2BNoypI7CB33tERDrYlEARaJt8UlYQcdB6ljcVdsEFOK3m8DfXtIaIXxU8oJAJQEH1avdj%2FOp6BFjBjsAot5IfssLbYgHxcRYO25vc7wigDPIQYpF3oXbx38%2BlvxUJJ1Tzic34uff03HC%2Bh1raIqAv93osiYqG4ueeptW1lefPo%2BBypdb2xONUujVv0P0meEWdyvcV4Mg2juDWC64UUqK2qOYoj184sZ5hnNCmyIDdQHib2dFmaFLtyTAu%2FbnNaHv2IEHVLPfW%2B%2FH%2FTkdYkZ6zDC1eOJBjqlAW2aGzleCiszR5evdSJnxX5r8V68db0cGCP%2BEIqp7IOGhkW6t9NVEQ0CoCYhj9TDT5x0QbIaKmMDLUCRmHfta7rJFQ40xLcNnVNWlu%2FjvmXGpW6b27cIHCnredGwVysHxVyvDPhk4jfbNKxjgOuVdM054ZzZwvDoGqS3XqGLAHSWO1HRz35xtyCBNEEu6uO4n9X3HO2zHHBYyyi6ATJSj2Hg6w4gWA%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20210908T175223Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYUPWZR2MR%2F20210908%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=c7095a2b6940335179bcece921f9d91a493081a547def9716d7ee4275b57f463&hash=10dba401723df90a52819d17d3307ac5d8b1957c86a4f53acc3fdff411ed9d52&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022314X05800290&tid=spdf-aacf4b25-5fc8-494d-b04e-9c29d0f552eb&sid=32a4627153179846670855a4fc2f2c540ad2gxrqb&type=client).

Comment: Is there a way to use any of this information to answer my original question (_i.e._ what is a representation of $a$ in terms of $b$, without nested radicals)?

Comment: Well, you could write $a=13b$ but that is probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: No: I’m _trying to prove_ $a=13$ without relying on previous results. Perhaps I can use your answer to prove $13 \mid a$… I’ll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan I've changed the article behind the link; the original article refers to this one for the specific case $X^2-2Y^4=-1$. The proof is quite involved.

Comment: You could represent $a$ without nested radicals using the formulae for $b$ and $n$ where $8b^2+1=n^2$:   $b = \frac{(3 + 2 \sqrt{2})^k - (3 - 2 \sqrt{2})^k} {4 \sqrt{2}} $ and $n =  (\frac{1}{2} ((3 - 2 \sqrt{2})^k + (3 + 2 \sqrt{2})^k))$.  Using these formulae ,with some manipulation, $a^2 = \frac{1}{4}(10-7\sqrt{2})(17-12\sqrt{2})^k + \frac{1}{4}(10+7\sqrt{2})(17+12\sqrt{2})^k $.  Expanding the terms, all the surds cancel out. However, I'm not sure whether it is of any practical use.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram Alpha tells me that integer solutions to $8b^2+1 = n^2$ are of the form

$b = \frac{(3 + 2 \sqrt{2})^k - (3 - 2 \sqrt{2})^k} {4 \sqrt{2}} $

$n =  (\frac{1}{2} ((3 - 2 \sqrt{2})^k + (3 + 2 \sqrt{2})^k))$

for positive integer $k$.

Alternatively, solutions to $8b^2+1=n^2$ can be obtained by treating it as a Pell equation and using  Brahmagupta's fomula to generate solutions.

Trying values of $k$ up to $25000$, where $b$ has 19139 digits,  results in only one solution where $a$ is an integer, for $k=1$, where $b=1$,  $a=13$.

My suspicion is that this could be the only solution.

Code for the search:

```
from gmpy2 import isqrt

def add( p, q ):
  return ( p[0]*q[0]+8*p[1]*q[1], p[0]*q[1]+q[0]*p[1])

X=(1,0)
for k in range(1,100000):
  X = add ( X,(3,1))
  (n,b) = X
  assert 8*b*b+1==n*n

  a2 = 28*b*n + 80*b*b + 5

  a = isqrt(a2)

  assert a*a <= a2 and a2 <= (a+1)**2
  if a*a==a2:
    print ("solution", b,n, a)

  if k%1000==0:
    print ("tried k=",k,", b has ",len(str(b)),"digits")
```

Comment: Yes, I’m trying to prove that $a=13$ is the only solution.

Comment: @Arthur Vause, $b=1$ $\rightarrow a^2=337$ so $a\neq 13$ am I right?

Comment: @sirous, $ b=1 \rightarrow n=3, a^2 = 28bn +80b^2+5 = 28*1*3 + 80*1*1 + 5 = 169$.  It looks like you have set $n=9$, not $n=3$